# Rails 3.1 - Events based on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, time, process, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an 'Event' model that contains a list of events along with their start time.

When the current time reaches the event start time, I would like to fire some action.

In other words, I want to do something whenever an event starts.

How can I accomplish this in Ruby / Rails ?

Comment: How much precision do you want? Do start times happen on the minute, on the second..? Do you want to "fire some action" on the client or only on the server side? We need more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with this. Either you write a script that checks the Events permanently and triggers some action when the event date is in the past or you use a gem for that. I would suggest you to watch some of the background job screencasts that deal with your problem:

http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32

Comment: @Jordan - Second precision is preferred. But, minute precision would be ok as well. The action would need to be fired on the server side.